# Custom screeshot for watir-rspec reporter

Tags: rspec, watir, watir-webdriver

I am migrating from watir-webdriver with rspec to watir-rspec (not a big change). But now I want to make use of the reporter to link the screenshots I take with the screenshot gem. I am struggling on how to to this and I don't want to use the standards screenshots because I have another helper function that does some work on the image and the screenshot gem allows me to get screenshots of specific elements.

On the watir-rspec documentation it claims we just have to add this three lines, but I am not sure where and how to change it to fit with my custom image generation.

```
uploaded_file_path = Watir::RSpec.file_path("uploaded.txt")
File.open(uploaded_file_path, "w") {|file| file.write "Generated File Input"}
file_field(:name => "upload-file").set uploaded_file_path
```

Comment: Do you always want to add the screenshot or just when the test fails?

Comment: I want to be able to add my own screenshots from another folder to the test cases. Would be enough just when the test fails, I guess.

Comment: Do the files have to be in another folder? It looks like Watir-RSpec expects the images to be saved in the results folder.

Comment: For organisation it would be better, yeah. But just to make it work I would test on the same folder, any ideas? I am looking at the HtmlFormatter code and I think I would still have to override a few methods to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding file links to the report is done by using the `Watir::RSpec.file_path` method. Basically you:

1. Call the `file_path` method, which tells the report to add a link and returns the path of the file expected.
2. Create the file, in this case screenshot, using the path returned by `file_path`.

In the following example, the After hook shows how the `file_path` method would be used to add a link:

```
require_relative "spec_helper"

describe "Google" do
  before { goto "http://google.com" }

  it "allows to search" do
    text_field(:name => "q").set "watir"
    button(:id => "gbqfb").click # This will fail to locate the element
    results = div(:id => "ires")
    results.should be_present.within(2)
    results.lis(:class => "g").map(&:text).should be_any { |text| text =~ /watir/ }
    results.should be_present.during(1)
  end

  after do
    # Call Watir::RSpec.file_path to:
    #  1. Tell the report to add a link
    #  2. Determine the file path/name the report will link to
    screenshot_file_path = Watir::RSpec.file_path("custom_screenshot.jpg")
    #=> "C:/Scripts/Misc/Programming/watir-rspec/spec/tmp/spec-results/custom_screenshot_104027_1_1.jpg"

    # Create the screenshot to the path specified in screenshot_file_path
    # This would be dependent on your screenshot gem
  end
end
```

There are a couple of limitations:

1. The linked image is expected to be in the results folder.
2. The linked image is expected to have a specific generated name.
3. While you can always create the screenshot, it will only be linked to the report if the test fails.
4. The default screenshot link will also exist.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tips @JustinKo, I managed to fix it overriding the extra_failure_content(exception) method from the HtmlFormatter class. I substituted the save_screenshot call with a custom call to get my own screenshots, and it worked great. I am saving them on the same directory to make it easier.

Here is the link for the HtmlFormatter original code.
https://github.com/watir/watir-rspec/blob/master/lib/watir/rspec/html_formatter.rb

```
class MyHtmlFormatter < Watir::RSpec::HtmlFormatter
 def my_custom_function(description)
  file_name = file_path("your_file.png", description)
  old = File.absolute_path("your_file.png") 
  File.rename(old, file_name)
  file_name
 end

 def extra_failure_content(exception)
    browser = example_group.before_all_ivars[:@browser] || $browser
    return super unless browser && browser.exists?
    my_custom_function args
    save_html browser
    (...)
 end
```